# Displaying attributes for associated models in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

I want to fetch username or email( both are in user table) of user who creates article in blog application. Currently I am able to fetch user id from articles_controller.rb

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.user_id = current_user.id
  @article.save
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

but no idea how to fetch username or email for same. Basically I want to display username or email on article index page. Please suggest me to how to get done it

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
    has_many :comments
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
   attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user.id
      @article.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy
      redirect_to action:  'index'  
    end

    def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
     end
end
```

article/index.html.erb

```
 <div style="color:#666666; margin-top:10px"> <%= article.created_at %></div>
     <div style="color:#666666; margin-top:10px"> <%= article.user_id %></div>
```

Articles table

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text  :body 
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :articles, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

I am able to fetch user id in views but no idea how to username or email.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined a `user` association on your `Article` model class with `belongs_to :user`. This creates a `user` method on `Article` that returns the associated user so you in your view:

```
<%= article.user.email %>
```

will output the email of the associated user, or:

```
<%= article.user.email if article.user %>
```

to cater for nil user values. Alternatively write a helper to factor this logic out of the view.

Comment: hi when tried to implement your suggestion, I got NoMethodError in Articles#index

Showing F:/24/billi/app/views/articles/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass error.

Comment: hi Steve, do i need to change code in my articles_controller.rb file. because in create action in article controller, I am getting current user id but no email. What do you suggest?

Comment: ok so you have some records in your articles table that don't have a user_id value set. You will need to defensively code around the article.user returning nil. I updated the answer.

Comment: Re second comment: No you don't need to do any more in your controller. You are setting the user_id and that is enough to associate the article with that user.

Comment: hi steve, updated answer worked for me . thanks you. Could you please explain bit why <%= article.user.email if article.user %> worked but not <%= article.user.email %>. I think you just added if condition which checks user is there or not and in my application user is there,still i was showing error. Any idea. thanks angain, i was stuck from last 5 hours ":)

Comment: If `user_id` is nil then article.user returns nil. nil is just an object in Ruby but it does not have an `email` method (thats why you got the error). Adding an end-of-line `if` will ensure that the line only gets executed when the if evaluates true. So to handle your error `if article.user` prevents you calling the `email` method on nil.

Comment: great explanation. thnaks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Already you set relation between the Article & User model. So in your article index page you have all articles in @articles variable. So easily you can get the particular user of a particular article using below code,

```
@articles.each do |article|
  user = article.user #gives the user of this current article. From this  
                      #objecct you can easily get the username, email or everything specific to user.
  email = user.email  #gives email of article's user or you can directly give artile.user.email
end
```

like this you can get all the attribute of user.

Comment: hi Mohanrja, thanks, I got answer using <%= article.user.username if article.user %>.